# Application Error Found in Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have hosted my app first time in Heroku. it works on my localhost but when I hosted it on Heroku it gives Application error: An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. i check my logs and logs are:

```
  $ heroku logs --app peaceful-wildwood-9840
  ←[36m2014-06-08T18:48:05.660654+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Enable Logplex by aminayo
 usuf_13@hotmail.com
  ←[36m2014-06-08T18:48:05.660736+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Release v2 created by ami
  nayousuf_13@hotmail.com
  ←[33m2014-06-08T18:49:27+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]:←[0m Slug compilation start
  ed
  ←[36m2014-06-08T18:49:33.638541+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Deploy 2ab14e4 by aminayo
 usuf_13@hotmail.com
  ←[36m2014-06-08T18:49:33.511107+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Scale to web=1 by aminayo
  usuf_13@hotmail.com
  ←[36m2014-06-08T18:49:33.638621+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Release v3 created by ami
  nayousuf_13@hotmail.com
  ←[33m2014-06-08T18:49:33+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]:←[0m Slug compilation finis
 hed
   ←[32m2014-06-08T18:49:36.203628+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Listening to Port : 3033..
 .  
   ←[32m2014-06-08T18:49:35.293036+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with c
  ommand `node server.js`
  ←[32m2014-06-08T18:50:37.170068+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from star
  ting to crashed
  ←[32m2014-06-08T18:50:37.170632+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from cras  
  hed to starting
  ←[32m2014-06-08T18:50:39.419734+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Listening to Port : 3033..
 .
 ←[32m2014-06-08T18:50:35.901399+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Error R10 (Boot timeout )
 -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
 ←[32m2014-06-08T18:50:35.901708+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Stopping process with S  
 IGKILL
  ←[32m2014-06-08T18:50:37.165375+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with sta
  tus 137
  ←[32m2014-06-08T18:50:38.558505+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with c
  ommand `node server.js`
  ←[35m2014-06-08T18:51:20.593335+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H20 desc
 ="App boot timeout" method=GET path=/ host=peaceful-wildwood-9840.herokuapp.com
  request_id=aabed091-9c41-4639-9069-c02f8dd71503 fwd="39.48.218.219" dyno= connec 
  t= service= status=503 bytes=
   ←[35m2014-06-08T18:51:32.899300+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H20 desc
    ="App boot timeout" method=GET path=/ host=peaceful-wildwood-9840.herokuapp.com
    request_id=db181007-c7dd-47ba-a42f-91def32077df fwd="39.48.218.219" dyno= connec
   t= service= status=503 bytes=
  ←[32m2014-06-08T18:51:39.895529+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from star  
  ting to crashed
  ←[35m2014-06-08T18:51:40.797283+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc
 ="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=peaceful-wildwood-9840.herokuap
  p.com request_id=e63e5ee2-b04e-4b13-8e61-77d1f4f4600b fwd="39.48.218.219" dyno=   
  connect= service= status=503 bytes=
  ←[35m2014-06-08T18:51:40.926423+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc
  ="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=peaceful-wildwood-9840.herokuapp.com reque
  st_id=88b77ad4-7547-4b41-b6c8-b820a38284b5 fwd="39.48.218.219" dyno= connect= se
 rvice= status=503 bytes=
  ←[35m2014-06-08T18:51:42.930361+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc
 ="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=peaceful-wildwood-9840.herokuap
 p.com request_id=010dcdf3-e68a-47bb-a821-6dd5613b14ce fwd="39.48.218.219" dyno=
  connect= service= status=503 bytes =
  ←[32m2014-06-08T18:51:39.887550+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with sta
 tus 137
  ←[32m2014-06-08T18:51:38.819255+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Error R10 (Boot timeout
 ) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
 ←[32m2014-06-08T18:51:38.819499+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Stopping process with S
   IGKILL
 ←[35m2014-06-08T18:51:52.977231+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc
 ="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=peaceful-wildwood-9840.herokuap
 p.com request_id=2ea71012-34e4-4361-9e04-9a1ae91716fa fwd="39.48.218.219" dyno=
 connect= service= status=503 bytes=
 ←[35m2014-06-08T18:56:28.116367+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc
 ="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=peaceful-wildwood-9840.herokuapp.com reque
  st_id=597301b8-8be8-46f0-96a9-43bb5425395a fwd="39.48.218.219" dyno= connect= se
 rvice= status=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error, as shown above, is `Error R10 (Boot timeout )
 -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch`.  I can think of two things that can cause this:

- Your startup is taking a long time - for example you're calling out to external web services while starting.
- Or you're not listening to the right port, so as a result you'll never bind to the right port.

I'm guessing it's the second?  What PORT number do you use?  Do you do something like this?
`var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 5000);`

Comment: i have added my application again with port 3033 but stil i am getting the same error

Comment: i have set my port to: app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3033);                                  @John Mountjoy